# Re the Fokker-Planck equation: How to reconcile boundary conditions for reflecting barriers with arbitrary initial conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, boundary-value-problem, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm learning about boundary conditions for the Fokker-Planck equation and am misunderstanding something fundamental.

In one dimension, the Fokker-Planck equation is
$$\partial_t f(x,t) = - \partial_x j(x,t)$$
where $f(x,t)$ is the distribution of $x$ and $j(x,t)$ is the probability flux:
$$j(x,t) = A(x,t)f(x,t) - \partial_x B(x,t)f(x,t)$$
My textbook (Gardiner) says that the boundary condition for a reflecting barrier at $x=a$ is
$$0 = j(a,t)$$

**My question is**: how can we reconcile this boundary condition with arbitrary initial distributions?  I.e. there could be many initial distributions $f(x,0)$ such that $j(x,0)\neq 0$.  Is the answer that the boundary conditions only hold for $t>0$?

**As an example**: consider the case with reflecting barriers at $a$ and $b$, and $x$ is a Wiener process with no drift, so that $A(x,t)=0$ and $B(x,t)=B$.  In this case the flux is:
$$j(x,t) = - B \partial_x f(x,t)$$
and the Fokker-Planck equation is
$$\partial_t f(x,t) = B \partial_x^2 f(x,t)$$
The boundary conditions for the reflecting barriers are
$$ 0 =  B \partial_x f(a,t) =  B \partial_x f(b,t)$$

The stationary distribution on $[a,b]$ is clearly $f(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}$.  But suppose the initial condition is something non-constant but still smooth, e.g. $f(x,0)=c e^{-x}$ (for an appropriate integrating coefficient $c$).  In this case, the flux is
$$j(x,0) = B f(x,0)$$ which is non-zero at the barriers $a$ and $b$, even though they must be reflecting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just considering the PDE, what will happen is that a discontinuity in the derivatives will occur at $(x,t) = (a,0)$, which will be evolved forward by the flow. For the diffusive case, this will smooth out, but for a purely drift case, the discontinuity will remain.

What is happening here is that often the PDE can be defined in a more general way (weak form) that allows for unique solutions when the initial conditions are not smooth, or not even continuous is some cases. In this setting, the boundary conditions are only applied for $t>0$. If the initial conditions match the boundary conditions, then the limit $\lim_{t\to0} f(\cdot,t) = f(0,\cdot)$ will hold in stronger topologies, e.g., smooth or continuous functions. However, this is not necessary for the evolution equation to be well-defined, although it requires some technical mathematics to get to that point.

Comment: This is helpful thank you.  I'd like to check if I understand: 

Does this imply that e.g. $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \partial_x f(x,0) \neq \partial_x f(a,0)$, and instead $\partial_x f(a,0)$  and $\partial_x^2 f(a,0)$ are given to satisfy the flux equation?

Then, suppose I go on to solve the PDE for every $t\geq0$.  I need boundary conditions to do so.  In the diffusive case, does it "smooth out" immediately? I.e. can I use $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \partial_x f(x,t>0) = \partial_x f(a,t>0)$?  Or is it more complicated?

Comment: The first limit has nothing to do with the PDE, so that just depends on whether the initial condition is smooth. For the diffusion equation, it does smooth out immediately, so the last limit you wrote is true in all cases I can think of.

Comment: I guess I remain a bit confused when you say "The first limit has nothing to do with the PDE".  Could you elaborate on which derivatives you refer to when you say "Just considering the PDE, what will happen is that a discontinuity in the derivatives will occur at  $(x,t)=(a,0)$"?

Comment: The first limit only has to do with the initial condition, as the PDE only governs what happens after $t=0$. As for my other statement, there will be a discontinuity in $f_x$, but specifically as a function of time. That is, $f_x(a,t)$ is discontinuous at $t=0$. Depending on the PDE, the solution can contain discontinuities away from the boundary at $t>0$ as well.